# Сделать ссылку в нижней части изображения

Tags: html, css

Как сделать изображение, чтобы в его нижней части можно было разместить гиперссылку ? Технологии html, css. Таблицы использовать не хочу.
Примерно как на рисунке ниже:
[image: http://tarem.ru/Foto/temp/image-with-link-css.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6HBzy/

html

```
<div>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSndDIwcAJWITtP_sb_NQPov5fsJXLdbhYB0b_yS5gi5WmUcM6yZA" alt="" />
    <a href="">Ссылка</a>
</div>
```

css

```
div{    
    position: relative;
    width: 290px;
    height: 174px;
}
div a{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);    
    position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: soledar10, спасибо! То, что нужно.